# How can I restore more windows than just my browser using dconf-editor?

Tags: firefox, cinnamon, session, dconf

#### System:

Ubuntu 18.04
Cinnamon 3.8.3
dconf-editor 3.28.0

I have been trying to save my workspace sessions so that when I start up my system, all the programs I want to open are there and ready to go, in multiple workspaces. I am trying to use dconf-editor to achieve this. I have followed instructions for auto-saving the session by going to `org > cinnamon > cinnamon-session` and enabling auto-save-session.

I opened some programs to test:

- Intellij Idea
- Terminal x4
- Firefox

I then restarted my system to find that only Firefox had reopened again, on the correct workspace.

Does anyone know how I could get the rest of my programs to open up after startup?